# ./waf command not working

Tags: waf, ns-3

I am using ns-3.16 in ubuntu 12.04. I'm new to python as well as ns3. When I run this ./waf (or any other waf command) it produces the following code:

```
   Waf: Entering directory `/home/hp/ns-3.16-git-master/build'
Waf: Leaving directory `/home/hp/ns-3.16-git-master/build'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hp/ns-3.16-git-master/.waf-1.6.11-30618c54883417962c38f5d395f83584/waflib/Scripting.py", line 97, in waf_entry_point
    run_commands()
  File "/home/hp/ns-3.16-git-master/.waf-1.6.11-30618c54883417962c38f5d395f83584/waflib/Scripting.py", line 151, in run_commands
    run_command(cmd_name)
  File "/home/hp/ns-3.16-git-master/.waf-1.6.11-30618c54883417962c38f5d395f83584/waflib/Scripting.py", line 143, in run_command
    ctx.execute()
  File "/home/hp/ns-3.16-git-master/.waf-1.6.11-30618c54883417962c38f5d395f83584/waflib/Scripting.py", line 345, in execute
    return execute_method(self)
  File "/home/hp/ns-3.16-git-master/.waf-1.6.11-30618c54883417962c38f5d395f83584/waflib/Build.py", line 98, in execute
    self.execute_build()
  File "/home/hp/ns-3.16-git-master/.waf-1.6.11-30618c54883417962c38f5d395f83584/waflib/Build.py", line 107, in execute_build
    self.compile()
  File "/home/hp/ns-3.16-git-master/.waf-1.6.11-30618c54883417962c38f5d395f83584/waflib/Build.py", line 182, in compile
    self.producer.start()
  File "/home/hp/ns-3.16-git-master/.waf-1.6.11-30618c54883417962c38f5d395f83584/waflib/Runner.py", line 149, in start
    self.refill_task_list()
  File "/home/hp/ns-3.16-git-master/.waf-1.6.11-30618c54883417962c38f5d395f83584/waflib/Runner.py", line 98, in refill_task_list
    self.outstanding.extend(self.biter.next())
  File "/home/hp/ns-3.16-git-master/.waf-1.6.11-30618c54883417962c38f5d395f83584/waflib/Build.py", line 396, in get_build_iterator
    self.post_group()
  File "/home/hp/ns-3.16-git-master/.waf-1.6.11-30618c54883417962c38f5d395f83584/waflib/Build.py", line 380, in post_group
    f()
  File "/home/hp/ns-3.16-git-master/.waf-1.6.11-30618c54883417962c38f5d395f83584/waflib/extras/compat15.py", line 114, in post
    return old_post(self)
  File "/home/hp/ns-3.16-git-master/.waf-1.6.11-30618c54883417962c38f5d395f83584/waflib/TaskGen.py", line 110, in post
    v()
  File "/home/hp/ns-3.16-git-master/src/wscript", line 436, in apply_ns3header
    dst_node = ns3_dir_node.find_or_declare(src_node.name)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_or_declare
```

How should I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

That's just mean your ns3_dir_node is None. Thus it has no find_or_declare method. You have to look at your script to find why your ns3_dir_node id None.